# ASP.NET MVC - How can I handle thousands of users sending HTTP requests at the same time?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, iis

I'm developing a Web Application that will be responsible for downloading some HTML documents from different websites.

```
public ActionResult DownloadHTML (List<string> URLs)
{
    foreach (var URL in URLs)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownLoadStringAsync(URL);
        var result = DoSomethingElse(URL)
    }
    return Json(Success = true)
}
```

At the moment, I have tested it with 10 users so I didn't have any issues so far. But what about when 10K people attempt to execute the same function and download an HTML Document from a website? I neither want to cause problems to any website by sending millions of requests or make my application unreliable.

I was thinking of creating some kind of queue in server's cache and execute each request over time when the amount of requests is larger than a certain amount. Not sure if it's possible or practical tho.

What would be the best way to prevent/handle this kind of scenario?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Well, you can use asyn approach.

Comment: @AsifRaza yes but what about when XXXX amount of users attempt to download HTML document from 'www.website.com' at the same time? As far as I know async would not prevent the application from attempting to send the requests at the same time

Comment: Asyn will make your application access parallel. Also depend on server where you hosted on application.

Comment: Your question is too broad. That will depend on a number of factor. (1) bandwidth of you application (2) resources size/file size which you want to download (3) the nature of the document means static or dynamic data in your file (4) if you want to cache then for how long you can cache (5) async is a good option but alone it won't work.

Comment: It's too early for you to make the decision. A popular site (consider Google/Facebook) has no issue handling millions of requests in seconds, so your upstream URLs might work just fine. You should only respond when you hit a real bottleneck.

Comment: since the development of this application is still in its very early stages, what would be the appropriate precautions to take in order to make it more scalable? thanks

Comment: Are 10,000 people likely to download a file from your website at the same time ? Consider using a CDN